# Prevent UIButton press when scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have two UIButtons in table cells that inconveniently press when scrolling. How can I prevent this?

Is there some property or sent event I can set so the button is only pressed when a user releases the press rather than as soon as the button is pressed?

I played around with the different touch events (Touch Up Inside and Touch Down) and neither seemed to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can listen for the tableview's scrolling delegate callbacks and turn off your buttons they are being scrolled

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)activeScrollView {

    //I assume the buttons are within your cells so you will have to enable them within your cells so you will probably have to handle this by sending a custom message to your cells or accessing them with properties.
    [yourButton setEnabled: NO];
}
```

and listen for

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
   // do the same to enable them back
   [yourButton setEnabled: YES];
}
```

Comment: This works if you press the button while you are already scrolling. The real issue I'm having is if you start the scroll gesture on top of a button, it fires the button even if you release outside of the button.

Answer (score 0):

In interface builder change the tag values of the buttons to a number greater than 10 (or some value). Subclass UIScrollView and override:

```
-(BOOL) touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view {

if(view.tag>10) {
    NSLog(@"should A");
    return YES;
} else return NO;
```

}

Your scrollView should have the property `canCancelContentTouches` set to YES and `delaysContentTouches` set to NO